# React-Native ActivityIndicator doesn't hide after animation finish

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, uiactivityindicatorview, activity-indicator

I have an **ActivityIndicator** that shows while fetch is loading and the wheel disappears when **componentDidMount** is fired, but keeps and empty block space in the layout. I'm guessing how to unmount this component but anything worked for me.

I'm currently working with these versions:

```js
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.40.0
```

This is part of the code I'm using:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ... // Couple more components here
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

import NewsList from './NewsList';

export default class HomeView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       noticias: [],
       animating: true,
     };
   }

componentDidMount(){
    fetchFunction() // My fetch function here
      .then(data => this.setState({ data:data }))
      this.state.animating = false
  }

render() {

    return (
        <View>
            <NewsList data={data} /> // My custom component

            <ActivityIndicator
            animating={this.state.animating}
            style={[{height: 80}]}
            color="#C00"
            size="large"
            hidesWhenStopped={true}
            />
        </View>
    );

  }
}
```

PS: I'm not using Redux.

[ActivityIndicator with animation working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc09N.png)
[The empty space when animating is set to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMQ7y.png)

Comment: `this.state.animating = false` why didn't you use setState as in the previous line?

Comment: I changed to:
`.then(data => this.setState({ data:data, animating: false }))`
and got the same results

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I recommend you to read more about JSX on how to show content conditionally https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

I would completely remove `ActivityIndicator` from the DOM when we are not loading anything

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

import NewsList from './NewsList';

export default class HomeView extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchFunction()
      .then(data => this.setState({ data, isLoading: false }))
  }

  render() {
    const {data, isLoading} = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <NewsList data={data} />
        {isLoading && (
          <ActivityIndicator
            style={{ height: 80 }}
            color="#C00"
            size="large"
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this help me a lot. I will check the JSX docs. 
Now is working as expected :)

Comment: If all is ok mark this answer as correct so others find it easily :)

Answer (score 4):

You should be using setState if you want your Component to be rendered again.

```
this.setState({ animating: false })
```

instead of

```
this.state.animating = false
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm new with React (like a week or so), so I didn't noticed the error in that line. Thanks for taking the time to mention it, now I fix it but the "blank" space persists :(